# Transfer text between iphones using WiFi network

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, file-transfer

i need to list out all the network devices connected in my same network and also need to transfer text to another network devices(iphone or ipad).can u help me to do it?provide me any sample applications url?

Comment: same question in another way....

Comment: i listed out the devices and need to transfer text

Comment: done the work successfully...

Comment: Hi Christina. May you please explore how you make this possible ? Can you implement something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541849/ios-upload-files-over-wifi-to-app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like Boujour to find advertised servers and then a TCP type socket for sending the files. The other devices (if they were iOS devices, would need to be running their server app - I dont think there is a way to background it). You could also use GameKit, but file transfer over Bluetooth is supposed to be kinda spotty, so you would have to try the wifi path instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use bonjour to search for devices. Then use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to send and receive data.