# iOS upload files over wifi to app

Tags: ios, file-upload

I am developing an App that needs to support transfer files over a local wifi network like goodread app does.

The idea is that iPhone app creates an HTTP server accessible through a web browser displaying a form to upload files to the app.

1. Press in my app the wifi transfer option
2. Visit an ip address like: 192.168.0.12:port
3. Upload files to my app using that page

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hi have you find the way to do so. I am feeling the same issue and would like to find a way for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code links:

upload to iPhone via web: https://plink.ucloud.com/public_link/link/9ba125f02169e4e3

upload to iPhone via ftp: https://plink.ucloud.com/public_link/link/9c53e777455a6085

Comment: link broken =(
Could you upload again please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a web server which is easy to integrate, check out Mongoose:

http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

Other options may be using Bonjour or just simply enabling the user to drop content into the app's Inbox via iTunes.

Comment: thanks, but then how can I configure it in order to transfer files to the application?

Comment: It ain't easy. You're going to want to find a tutorial, because it's not overly simple